# CSS select every other pair element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a simple unordered list.

```
<ul>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Forth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
  <li>Sixth item</li>
</ul>
```

I need to be abel to select every other element in pairs. So basically, I need the first + second, fifth + sixth, and so on as the pattern will repeat indefinitely.

I want to avoid using javascript as this will be an angular app, so I don't to do any DOM manipulation.

I've tried messing with `nth-child()` equations but can't figure out what equation will give me what I need. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
li:nth-child(4n+1), li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

example on codepen: http://codepen.io/erikL/pen/qyeKc/

Answer (score 2):

you can select every fourth item minus 3 and 2 to include the first 2 one:

```
li:nth-child(4n-3),
li:nth-child(4n-2)
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GEJzo/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Both you and @LarryG have correct answers, just different approaches to it. Though he did answer first so Im going to give him the credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update:
now it is possible to use keywords `odd` and `even`.
Example: `p:nth-child(even){...}`